# Flutter: Error Message when building animations for android (_lifecycleState != _ElementLifecycle.defunct': is not true.)

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-animation

I encounter this issue when trying to use animations in Flutter, everything working fine as expected when i build for android, (animations are awesome by the way) , but as soon as I push a named route on the screen(redirect to a different screen), I start getting this warning on my console log.

```
_lifecycleState != _ElementLifecycle.defunct': is not true.
```

The application runs as expected but i am just not comfortable seeing this message pop up 100 times afterwards.

Comment: Perhaps you forget to `dispose` the animation.

Comment: Yeah, I actually did, but only just realized i needed to dispose it before the the super.dispose() method. I didn't realize the order mattered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I discovered that despite disposing the AnimationController object, I was not doing it in the right order.

So instead of this:

```
@override
void dispose(){
 super.dispose();
 animationController.dispose(); 
}
```

I needed to have one this:

```
@override
 void dispose(){
 animationController.dispose();
 super.dispose();
}
```

The error message is cryptic so I hope this helps someone out there.